# Get rid of UNIX redirection newly created file without using rm

Tags: awk, grep, filesystems, io-redirection, word-processing

Using below function to filter out text file and organize to new format.

Using unix redirection `>` command to create new files.

**How can I get rid of creating all new files**

> (e.g. ${file}_final_1.txt,${file}*only*${pattern}.txt)

**without deleting it afterword using `rm` command ?**

```
filter(){
  cat ${file}_1.txt | grep -v ${pattern} > ${file}_final_1.txt                            
  cat ${file}_1.txt | grep ${pattern} > ${file}_only_${pattern}.txt                        
  cat ${file}_only_${pattern}.txt  | nawk -F '|' '{ print $NF}' > ${pattern}_TS.txt        
  paste ${pattern}_TS.txt ${file}_only_${pattern}.txt > ${pattern}_TS_file.txt
  cat ${pattern}_TS_file.txt | grep "|${DT}|" | grep ${pattern} | sort -r | head -1 > ${file}_f.txt
  cat ${file}_f.txt >> ${file}_final_1.txt
  dos2unix ${file}_final_1.txt ${file}_final.txt
}
```

Comment: (1) You can avoid creating so many files if you build longer pipes instead of writing to a file only to read from it in the next step. This won't work with `paste` though, where in your case you need at least one regular file as input (unless you use process substitution, but not really useful in your case where `${file}_only_${pattern}.txt` is used twice). (2) Creating temporary files in a temporary directory (`mktemp -d`) allows you to remove them all by removing the directory (`rm -r …`). // This is not an answer because (1) does not "get rid of creating all" and (2) is not "without `rm`".

Comment: [I hope you're using zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68748/108618).

Comment: As a starting point, copy/paste that script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the many issues it'll tell you about.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can chain pipes as long as you like:

```
  cat ${file}_1.txt | grep ${pattern} > ${file}_only_${pattern}.txt                        
  cat ${file}_only_${pattern}.txt  | nawk -F '|' '{ print $NF}' > ${pattern}_TS.txt
```

could be replaces with

```
cat ${file}_1.txt | grep ${pattern} | nawk -F '|' '{ print $NF}' > ${pattern}_TS.txt
```

And so on... There is a limit on the command line, of course, but it is ridiculously large. Do `getconf ARG_MAX` and you'll get how many characters it is.

2. If some app does not accept input from a pipe, or it is easier to work with multiple files... Then you can always dump temp files into a temp directory. So your `filter()` function could follow a pattern:

```
filter(){
   TEMP_DIR=/tmp/dir_for_this_task_`date +%s`
   mkdir $TMP_DIR
   CUR_DIR=`pwd`
   cd $TMP_DIR

   .... your code with temp files

   cd $CUR_DIR
   rm -r $TMP_DIR
}
```

you can also use `pushd/popd` to remember current directory and return to it from temp.

Comment: 1. Use `mktemp` to create temporary files and directories 2. Double-quote your variables when you use them 3. Use `$(...)` instead of backticks

Comment: @roaima There are infinite ways to improve any script.

Comment: There are indeed, but writing incorrect code is poor

Comment: @roaima `$(...)` is a bashism, backticks work in every POSIX shell.

Comment: @allo no, it's part of the spec for all POSIX shells, see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_03 and other parts of the spec.